# I'm trying to use safe args but when i add the dependencies to the project level build.gradle it gives me this error

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle

```
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
   id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
dependencies {
   "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$version_navigation"
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'version_navigation' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: Kindly go through the link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You cannot use the `dependencies` block in the *root* of the `build.gradle` from *project module*. The correct way is to add the `buildscript` block and the `dependencies` inside it, like this:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

Remembering that you also have the option to follow the new structure pattern, and instead of using the `dependency` block, you can use the `plugins` block:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version '2.5.3' apply false
}
```

In the `build.gradle` from *app module*, it remains the same as it always was.

```
plugins {
    // ...
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

You must ensure that a library's dependencies follow the same version to avoid problems. 
To facilitate this versioning when you need the version in more than one *gradle* file, you can also include an `ext` block inside of `buildscript` in the `build.gradle` from *project module* with the version and use it in place of the version number in the *gradle* files. Full example:

`build.gradle` (project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        navigation_ver = '2.5.3'
    }

    // if you want the 'old' way:
    // dependencies {
        // classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigation_ver"
    // }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    // if you want the 'new' way:
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' version "$navigation_ver" apply false
}
```

`build.gradle` (app module)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_ver"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_ver"
}
```

Comment: How to tell that the previous dependency androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin will become androidx.navigation.safeargs?

Comment: @S.Gissel you don't have to tell, `gradle` will handle this structure internally automatically. `plugins` block is just another way to add the library to a project, you can use both `plugins id` and `dependencies classpath` simultaneously in the project (to add different libraries, not the same). More info on [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html)

Comment: Good job mentioning ext block.

Answer (score 2):

`build.gradle` from project module (Top-level build file):

just add `buildscript{..}` on top of the file.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle plugin:2.5.1")
  }
}

plugins {
  id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
  id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build.gradle` from app module:

if kotlin add next line into `plugins{..}`

```
id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

if java add next line into `plugins{..}`

```
id "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

add next line into `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Answer (score -1):

Add these line in dependencies block:

```kotlin
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.1")
```

if you want use another version so change in 2.5.1

Comment: oh sorry for that