# New projects' top level build.gradle just contains plugins section

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Newly created project has a top level build.gradle that is different to previous ones.

Instead of **buildscript**{**repositories**, **dependencies**...} it just contains **plugins{...}**.

I could manage to add Google GMS as plugin like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}
```

In previous projects Google GMS line looked like this (note the **colon**)

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

But I don't know how to add **Firebase Crashlytics** gradle plugin with new syntax. Before it was like this

```
// Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
```

Changing the line to

```
id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crashlytics-gradle' version'...' apply false
```

did not help.

I looked in **settings.gradle**, but in a new project no dependencies are defined here. I doubt they belong there.

Comment: Look in `settings.gradle`.

Comment: I explained about the new build structure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73208002/18943404). It's not about the `Firebase Crashlytics` but you can follow this anyway. Tip: the `Crashlytics` id to use is `com.google.firebase.crashlytics`